# Using itextsharp to set ocg state of existing pdf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, itext

I have spent several hours researching this and can't seem to locate the answer.
I have downloaded and referenced itextsharp in my wpf .net application. (VB)

What I am doing is needing to turn off a specific layer (ocg object) in an exisiting .pdf that was created in Autocad that is defaulted on.

I have successfully opened and displayed the .pdf but i can't seem to use the setOCGstate control correctly
pdf name is "random.pdf"

layer name that i can see once i open the .pdf is "Option 1"

where im getting stuck is i know the layer names are stored in an array inside the .pdf. i know the name of the layer i am trying to turn off, so how do i reference that layer and turn it off using the setocgstate.

example code

dim doc1 as New PdfReader("random.pdf")

PdfAction.SetOCGstate ("confused", False)

Comment: There is no relationship whatsoever between the `doc1` object and the line where you try setting the `OCGState`. Please show us what you've *really* tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an example that turns off the visibility of a specific layer. See [ChangeOCG](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/stamper/ChangeOCG)

The concept is really simple. You already have a `PdfReader` object and you want to apply a change to a file. As documented, you create a `PdfStamper` object. As you want to change an OCG layer, you use the `getPdfLayers()` method and you select the layer you want to change by name. (In my example, the layer I want to turn off is named "Nested layer 1"). You use the `setOn()` method to change its status, and you're done:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
Map<String, PdfLayer> layers = stamper.getPdfLayers();
PdfLayer layer = layers.get("Nested layer 1");
layer.setOn(false);
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

This is Java code. Please read it as if it were pseudo-code and adapt it to your language of choice.

Comment: Bruno thanks a lot, I am new to VB programming, but i think i can work through your very helpful example. thanks.